# how to draw on picture box without losing the content after minimizing, vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, drawing

When I minimize the form, I lose all the contents drawn on the picture box. I want it to be retain on the picture box. Please help me in this regard.
The code can be seen below..

```
Private Sub ButtonDraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDraw.Click
    Dim g As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
    Dim MyPen As New Pen(Color.Red)
    MyPen.Width = 2

    MyPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid

    g.TranslateTransform(PictureBox1.Width / 2, PictureBox1.Height / 2)
    g.DrawEllipse(MyPen, New Rectangle(-150, -150, 300, 300))
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove this: `Dim g As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()`, use the Paint event of `PictureBox1` to draw on its surface. Move all Graphics method inside the event handler (or, better, a method called from the event handler: pass the `e.Graphics` object to this method). -- The Pen is a disposable object, either Dispose() of it or declare it with a `using` statement.

Comment: can you please write a code for this? @Jimi

Comment: Maybe. Can you describe what this code is supposed to achieve? Why do you `TranslateTransform` half the size of a control, then add a rectangle with fixed measures? Did you mean to draw an ellipse (a Circle here) in the middle of your PictureBox?

Answer (score 1):

Example code, using `e.Graphics` in the `Paint()` event, as suggested by Jimi:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Using MyPen As New Pen(Color.Red)
        MyPen.Width = 2
        MyPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid

        g.TranslateTransform(PictureBox1.Width / 2, PictureBox1.Height / 2)
        g.DrawEllipse(MyPen, New Rectangle(-150, -150, 300, 300))
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: how to call this function , eg if I need to call it at different instances, how it can be done then..

Comment: If you want to force a repaint, call `PictureBox1.Invalidate()`.  If you're talking about more than one rectangle, then you need to store the information about each rectangle in a `List(Of Rectangle)` and then iterate over that in the `Paint()` event.  This way you can add something to the list and then invalidate causing the new thing to appear.

Comment: its working, but i don't think that its the only solution, since very difficult to work with this when you have to draw again and again..

Comment: It just depends on your end goal, and more importantly, whether you ever need to REMOVE things (or turn them "on" and "off").  If you only ever add things, then you could create a Bitmap and draw permanently to that, then just assign that to the `.Image` property of your PictureBox.

Comment: This is the standard way of drawing dynamic things, though.  For complex output, or if you have a large number of things, you may need to turn on double buffering and look at optimizing how much is drawn dynamically versus how much is "permanent" on a Bitmap.  You can combine the two methods and have some things in a Bitmap assigned to `.Image`, while other things are drawn "on top" of that in the `Paint()` event.